# Cómo crear hyperlink para el cuerpo de email en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

¿En qué formato debo enviar una url (string), para el cuerpo de un email, para que al abrir el nuevo email, la url me figure como un enlace? Probé de esta forma pero no reconoce correctamente las etiquetas:

```
const test = encodeURIComponent('<a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>')

<ShareEmailDataButton subjectMail={'asunto'} bodyMail={test} />
```

[image: como sale en el correo]

Answer (score -2):

Para crear un hipervínculo en el cuerpo de un correo electrónico, necesitás usar HTML en lugar de simplemente enviar una cadena de texto. Podés usar la etiqueta `<a>` en HTML para crear un hipervínculo, de la siguiente manera:

```
const body = `<p>Hola,</p>
<p>Aquí está el enlace que mencioné: <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a></p>
<p>Saludos,</p>`;
```

Después, podés enviar el cuerpo del correo electrónico como una cadena de texto HTML al componente que estés utilizando para enviar el correo electrónico. Estate seguro de usar la función *encodeURIComponent* para codificar la cadena antes de enviarla, para evitar problemas con caracteres especiales:

```
const encodedBody = encodeURIComponent(body);
<ShareEmailDataButton subjectMail={'asunto'} bodyMail={encodedBody} />
```

Comment: probé de esa forma y no estaría resultando 
me lo muestra asi en el email..

<p>Hola,</p>
<p>Aquí está el enlace que mencioné: <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a></p>
<p>Saludos,</p>